# Isolating test APK build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk, android-instrumentation

I have a situation where in an Android project with instrumentation tests I have all of the production code precompiled and ready to be installed as an `.apk` (a React Native environment).

Whenever I run instrumentation tests, I initially build the AndroidTest `.apk` using Gradle by running:

```sh
./gradlew assembleDebugAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug
```

(i.e. in a pretty standard way).

Trouble is that despite explicitly specifying only the `xxxAndroidTest` task, all of the production code assembly Gradle tasks are run as well. This is an extreme time waster to me since - as I explained, the production `apk` is already there, and thus code compilation (and packaging, signing, etc.) is scarce.

In essence, I have no dependency in production code from the instrumentation code -- even the `ActivityTestRule` I use is created dynamically and isn't directly bound to my *main* activity:

```java
Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = context.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(launchIntent, 0);
Class<?> activityClass = Class.forName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
ActivityTestRule<?> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule(activityClass, false, false);
```

Question is: How can I isolate / restrict Gradle's work so it would only include test-related tasks? I even tried inspecting the tasks tree using [this Gradle plugin](https://github.com/dorongold/gradle-task-tree), but couldn't find a clear place to "cut the tree" down.

Comment: how did you figured out that other assemble tasks are also getting executed when you run task 'assembleDebugandroidTest'. I tried the same thing using following command 'gradlew assembleDebugAndroidTest --debug > test_1.txt' and found that only 'assembleDebugAndroidTest' is getting executed. Mine is sample app.

Comment: @RanjanKumar well it's easy to spot numerous unrelated tasks such as `:<some-subproject>:compileDebugKotlin` while the build is running. In particular, I have one of those that takes almost 15s to run on my mac. Another option is to inspect the deps tree explicitly using the [gradle-task-tree](https://github.com/dorongold/gradle-task-tree) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Well so far I've come up with this (heuristic) solution, that does 2 things:

1. I noticed that most of the time that goes to waste is due to sub-projects that are not needed for the job. Therefore, the solution provides an easy way to exclude `implementation`s from *test* building.
2. Out of the tasks remaining in the list, still - the plugin iteratively force-disables tasks that are not related but run nonetheless.

It boils down to this helper Gradle script:

```
// turbo-test-apk.gradle

def isEnabled = System.getProperty('TURBO_TEST_APK') != null

project.ext.dependenciesExcludeTest = { depsClosure ->
    if (!isEnabled) {
        dependencies(depsClosure)
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
    if (isEnabled) {
        def disabledTasks = new ArrayList<Task>(graph.allTasks.size())

        [/.*JsAndAssets.*/, /package.*Release/, /package.*Debug/, /compile.*/, /.*[Pp]roguard.*/, /.*[Nn]ew[Rr]elic.*/, /.*AndroidTest.*/].forEach { regex ->
            graph.allTasks.findAll { it.name ==~ regex }.forEach({ task ->
                disabledTasks.add(task)
                task.enabled = false
            })
        }

        graph.allTasks.findAll { it.name ==~ /.*AndroidTest.*/ }.forEach({ task ->
            task.enabled = true
        })

        println '--- Turbo test build: task scanning ---'
        disabledTasks.forEach { task ->
            if (!task.enabled) {
                println 'Force-skipping ' + task
            }
        }
        println '---------------------------------------'
    }
}
```

Namely, the `dependenciesExcludeTest` enabled the exclusion of unwanted subprojects, and the task-graph-ready callback does the disabling. **NOTE that the regex list is custom made, and is not generic**. It makes sense for my project as react native projects have a heavy-weight JS-bundling tasks called `bundleJsAndAssets`, and I also have new relic installed. Nevertheless, this can be easily tailored to any project.

Also, the `app.gradle` looks something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply from: './turbo-test-apk.gradle'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:$kotlin_stdlib:$kotlinVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    // etc.
}
// These will be excluded when executing test-only mode
dependenciesExcludeTest {
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation project(':any-unneeded-sub-project')
}
```

So when gradle is run like this (i.e. with a custom TURBO_TEST_APK property):

```sh
./gradlew assembleDebugAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug -DTURBO_TEST_APK
```

the script will apply its work and reduce the overall build time.

This solution isn't optimal: tricky to maintain, doesn't omit **all** of the unnecessary work. I'd be very happy to see more effective solutions.